# Want to get the first word in string using sting.split function

Tags: java, string, split

```
public static String getFirstString(String str){
    String arr[] = str.split(" ", 2);
    String firstWord = arr[0]; 
    return firstWord;
}
```

i have made this function can any body tell me why i am using

```
String arr[] = str.split(" ", 2) "2" ,
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean - if you wrote the code, don't you know why you wrote what you did? Did you look up the Javadoc for what the `split` method does?

Comment: Jon Skeet , with due respect i know exactly what does it mean , but i want more purified answer .

Comment: Nope, that's no clearer. If you know exactly what it does, what can we do to help you? It's really, really unclear what you're hoping to get out of this question...

Comment: @JonSkeet Skeet , Number 2 in your split api usage means you want at max split your string into two parts. So if my string was "blah foo bar", then output you would get would be array of size 2 with content as array[0]="blah", array[1]="foo bar" As per javadoc it says: thats what i wanted

Comment: I don't know, Is it just me? The way I see it what you've provided ( String arr[] = str.split(" ", 2) "2" ) won't work at all. You can't even compile that however String arr[] = str.split(" ", 2) will work.

Comment: @DevilsHnd: And indeed that's what's in the actual code in the question - it's only the last part of the question which includes `"2"` there, for no obvious reason.

Comment: @WaseemSaeed: Right, so you were trying to ask what the method does, and the Javadoc clearly states what it does. So again, why did you ask the question?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, bcs people like me educate me more .

Comment: No, asking a question which is entirely answered by the documentation is simply unhelpful, and shows a lack of research, I'm afraid. That's compounded by asking the question unclearly. This is *not* a good question for Stack Overflow - hence the downvotes.

Comment: thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 2 in your `split` api usage (referred as limit parameter in split api) means you want at max split your string into two parts. So if my string was "blah foo bar", then output you would get would be array of size 2 with content as `array[0]="blah"`, `array[1]="foo bar"` As per javadoc it says:

> > The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

For details, you could refer to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

"2" is the limit parameter. It sets how many strings to be returned. Check [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for more details